# R how to merge 2 list

Tags: r, list, merge

I have 2 list in R like:

list1:

```
 [1] "Name1" "Name2" "Name3" "Name4" "Name5"    
 [6] "Name6" "Name7" "Name8" "Name9" "Name10"      
[11] "Name11" "Name12"
```

and a list of Color Codes

colors:

```
 [1] "#E91E63" "#2196F3" "#009688" "#FF9800" "#795548" "#91003f" "#4a148c" "#673AB7" "#03A9F4" "#33691e" "#FF5722"
[12] "#3F51B5"
```

So I want to merge and be like:

list_color

```
   Name1     Name2     Name3     Name4     Name5     Name6     Name7     Name8     Name9    Name10    Name11 
"#263238" "#bf360c" "#3690c0" "#8c96c6" "#E91E63" "#2196F3" "#009688" "#FF9800" "#795548" "#91003f" "#4a148c" 
   Name12 
"#673AB7"
```

the class correspond to character:

```
class(list_color)
[1] "character"
```

I Always do it manually :

```
list_colors <- c("Name1" = "#263238", "Name2" = "#bf360c", 
             "Name3" = "#3690c0", "Name4" = "#8c96c6", 
             "Name5" = "#E91E63", "Name6" = "#2196F3", 
             "Name7" = "#009688", "Name8" = "#FF9800", 
             "Name9" = "#795548", "Name10" = "#91003f", 
             "Name11" = "#4a148c", "Name12" = "#673AB7")
```

How could I do it in R ???

Comment: `setNames(colors, list1)` Or `names(colors) <- list1`